# Karate - Cannot cast java.util.LinkedHashMap to java.util.List

Tags: karate

I need to compare an XML file with that of Json response. Below is just a short version of original xml file, JSON and XML have different attribute names because of which i cannot compare them directly. I need to call function to format xml so that it can be compared with json. During this process, I am getting the error `Cannot cast java.util.LinkedHashMap to java.util.List` after running below code.

```
* xml list = $Test1/Body
* print list

* def xpath = function(x, p){ try { return karate.xmlPath(x, p) } catch (e) { return '#notpresent' } }
* def fun = function(x){ return { code: xpath(x, '/Body/code') } }
* def temp = karate.map(list, fun)
* print temp
```

Test1 is an xml file containing below sample data;

```
<ns9:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns5:plan">
  <ns4:code>XPBSMWAT</ns4:code>
</ns9:Body>
```

This is a simpler version of XML data; my actual xml file is bigger.

Comment: I'm lost. if you re-write your question with what exactly you are TRYING to do - that will allow others to help you

Comment: Thanks Peter, Added details in question.

Comment: try reading this a few times: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53474845/143475 - and you can't do a `karate.map()` on XML it has to be a JSON array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`karate.map` takes 2 arguments list and a function,

From your question,

```
* xml list = $Test1/Body
```

variable name `list` is actually of a `xml` data type as you defined, **not a list**.

karate takes XML/JSON as java.util.LinkedHashMap since you passed the XML as input to the map function it tried to cast it into List and failed.

So it should be something like,

```
* def list = <something>
```

But make sure instead of xml it returns a list

> Your xml path `$Test1/Body` returns xml
>
> when you print the list you will see it surrounded with **[** and
> **]**

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do with this xml and JS functions but this could be root cause for the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Babu for the informative answer, but I had tried this method as well. Still i get the same error. BTW, I added some more details in question.