# Comparing 2 Soap Requests in Karate framework

Tags: karate

I am new to webservice testing and I have started learning Karate to test APIs. I have been successful in building a basic smoke test suite that runs to see if the API is returning the right response using Karate framework.

I want to extend my validation of APIs further. What I want to achieve is - if a API has changed/updated, how do I know of those changes if no one told me?[in a big organization sometimes its hard to know if someone has made a change and checked in their code with some unit testing].
Is there a way to compare the 2 soap requests and pin-point what has changed?

Comment: please refer this. the rest is up to your research and creativity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53474845/143475

Comment: Thanks Peter! Appreciate your help :)