# Karate: Match JSON Array responses where the order of array is different in each hit

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where a portion of the response arrays is the response from a child API.
child API response looks like below, but there is no specific order. And I need to check whether the child API response is present in the parent API(irrespective of the order of the elements in the child API). I followed this [Karate - Match two dynamic responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118601/karate-match-two-dynamic-responses) thread but its not working in my case.

```
* def response1 =

    """
   {
    "array1": [
        {
            "element": {
                "id": "A1",
                "array11": [
                    {
                        "uid": "u123",
                        "gid": [
                            "g1"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "element": {
                "id": "A2",
                "array11": [
                    {
                        "uid": "u124",
                        "gid": [
                            "g2"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
"""
* def response2 =

    """
 {
    "array1": [
        {
            "element": {
                "id": "A2",
                "array11": [
                    {
                        "uid": "u124",
                        "gid": [
                            "g2"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "element": {
                "id": "A1",
                "array11": [
                    {
                        "uid": "u123",
                        "gid": [
                            "g1"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    ]
}
    """
```

Comment: Please add a programming language tag, otherwise the syntax highlighting doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one liner :)

```
* match response2.array1 contains response1.array1
```

Guess what, you don't have to match pure JSON all the time, using child-sections is fine.

But also read this specific part of the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#contains-short-cuts

And this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/graphql/graphql.feature

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas. In my case I need to check the size of the child api response, if the size of the array >1 then only I need to match those elements in the parent API response. If child API returns only one array, then that wont be populated in parent API. So I have made a JS function to check the responseStatus and the size of the child api response. How can I user `contains` in JS function?

Comment: @JCK Karate does not encourage you to do `match` or `contains` in JS, this is deliberate. you seem to be over-complicating your test. maybe it is time you ask a new question, keep it specific, and please try to use simpler examples and respect the time of people here trying to help you

Comment: I am not over-complicating I did not find a way in Karate to dot it so I used JS. Is there a way to do it in karate?

Comment: @JCK just my opinion. anyway, I don't understand your question, so I suggest you ask a new question with a *specific* example. or wait for someone else to provide anything I missed