# Comparing json in Karate

Tags: karate

I have two jsons array responses with same data but the attributes are different. How to compare this kind of jsons.

json 1:
comments: [
{
"onetag1": "1",
"onetag2": "2"
},
{
"onetag11": "3",
"onetage12": "4"
}
]

json 2:

newcommentslist: [
{
"newtag2": "2",
"newtag1": "1"
},
{
"newtag11": "3",
"newtage12": "4"
}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JsonPath:

```
* def first = [ { "onetag1": "1", "onetag2": "2" }, { "onetag11": "3", "onetage12": "4" } ]
* def values = $first[*].*
* match values == ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Or transform one of them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120851/143475

Comment: Thank you, using the transform