# org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException when '(' ')' used in regex in karate.match()

Tags: exception, karate, polyglot

I want to check whether the values in array match regex using 'karate.match'
But I'm getting polyglot exception because I have brackets in my regex, any idea how to fix this issue?

```
* def result= karate.match("each valueData == '#regex ^\'[A-Z0-9]+([\']?[,]?[\']?[A-Z0-9]+)*\'$'")
* match result == { pass:true, message:null }
* print result
```

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:41 Expected an operand but found )
'#regex ^'[A-Z0-9]+([']?[,]?[']?[A-Z0-9]+)*'$'
                                         ^
```

Comment: Text I want to match using regex can be,
'AAQS700CM'
or
'AAQS700CM','AERS700CM','BCNS700CM'

Comment: I'll pass, personally I think this is an over-complicated assertion, maybe you should just use a JS function like seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036047/143475