# Match each value of json with a regex and logical operator

Tags: karate

Consider below JSON. I want to match each of temp has a partial string matching 'process' using a OR condition i.e. in each temp either severity or conditionName should have a partial matching of 'process'

```
* def temp = [{ "severity": "Critical","conditionName": "process"}, { "severity": "Critical 2","conditionName": "process 2" }, { "severity": "Critical 2","conditionName": "processor" } ]
```

I tried below code:

```
* def isMatch = function(x) { return x.severity == '#regex (?i).*process.*' || x.conditionName == '#regex (?i).*process.*' }
* match each temp == '#? isMatch(_)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the things like `#regex` etc. work *only* for the Karate `match` keyword. You are attempting to use this in JavaScript code here, which will not work.

This should achieve what you want to do:

```
* def isMatch = function(x) { return x.severity.includes('process') || x.conditionName.includes('process') }
```

You can do more complicated matches (I think even regex in JS is possible) so keep that in mind. Also note that there is a `karate.match()` API - which will return an object with a `pass` property - but it depends on a variable being available in the Karate scope: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Comment: I already tried karate.match() and some of JS regex including 'includes'. The below error is what I got:
'TypeError: x.severity.includes is not a function in <eval>'

Comment: @SurajRavi can you please start testing the 1.0 RC version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide - else maybe `contains` would work instead of `includes`

Comment: I will try with 1.0 RC version and update here. I have already tried contains.

Comment: @SurajRavi well, it works for me. follow this process if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also my recommendation is try to convert your json into a "shape" easier to do a simple `match`, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120851/143475