# Iterate over complex JsonArray and pass value based on the index inside JsonPath

Tags: arrays, loops, iterator, karate

I am trying to iterate over the array and need to compare each item of the array with the template I am creating from another Json response. This is the sample response I am getting. It is much larger and size of the array is dynamic.

```
* def actual = 
"""
    { "id": "10103",
      "city": "xxx",
      "eq": "xxx",
      "noOfSqt": "20000"
     },
     { "id": "12394",
      "city": "xxx",
      "eq": "xxx",
      "noOfSqt": "20000"
     },
     { "id": "74747",
      "city": "xxx",
      "eq": "xxx",
      "noOfSqt": "20000"
     }
"""
```

From another json response I save ids in List. They are in a different order than the ids in"actual" array. Looks like that.

```
* def IDs = [12394, 74747, 10103]
```

This is my solution if I only have "actual" array of size 1, I am passing index 0. I get the first item from the IDs List, then retrieve the array item from "actual" array based on that ID.

```
* def i = 0              //index zero
* def index = IDs[i]     //first item of the array at index 0 is 12394
* def firstObject = karate.jsonPath(actual, "$[?(@.id == '" + index + "')]")[0] //array object where id is 12394

* def city = karate.jsonPath(someOtherJson, "$.loc[?(@.newID == '" + index + "')].value")[0]
* def eq = karate.jsonPath(someOtherJson, "$.mix[?(@.newID == '" + index + "')]..value")[0]
* def noOfSqt = karate.jsonPath(someOtherJson, "$.flat[?(@.newID == '" + index + "')].value")[0]
* def expected = 
"""
{
  "city": "#(city)",
  "eq": "#(eq)",
  "noOfSqt": "#(noOfSqt)"
}
"""

* match firstObject contains expected
```

Instead of passing i = o ( index zero), please help me to iterate, so I can compare each item of the array. I have reviewed karate.repeat, karate.apendTo, karate.forEach(), JS loop,  but still having issue implementing those. Also I am using contains instead == because the array and template have different number of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can achieve what you want in one line (in Karate 1.0 for the JS array map instead of `karate.map()`):

```
* match actual[*].id contains IDs.map(x => x + '')
```

I leave it as an exercise to you to figure out how that works.

Sometimes it is perfectly ok to convert your existing JSON to another "shape" using JsonPath expressions or `karate.map()`. Please read this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120851/143475

Comment: Can you please advice on a different approach I tried?