# Unordered array assertions in Karate

Tags: api, automation, karate, web-api-testing

I am working API testing where expected (source) and actual (target) both are apis. So I need to hit both apis dynamically with an account number and have to assert both expected and actual.

```
Feature: un ordered array assertions

   Scenario :
    * url 'https://source.org/anything'
    * path id
    * method get
    * def expected = expecteResponse.empDetails
    * url 'https://actual.org/anything'
    * path id
    * method get
    * def actual = actualResponse.emps
    * match expected  == actual
```

1. Here is my problem is expected [100,30,50], actual [50,100,30]. How can I assert them? And also, I need to validate string vs string (source = [sea,bus,air], target[bus,air,sea]) or integer vs float (Source = [10,1,20], target = [20.0,10.0,1.0]) or float vs integer (source =[20.0,10.0,1.0] target = [10,1,20]) or integer vs integer(source = [10,0,1] target = [0,10,1]. This my current.

But, it would be great if you answered for following questions (This top most problem for me to choose a framework to compare/validate apis which developed extract to api or api to api by using strapi technology)

2. Mostly my tickets like source and target - content-as-a-service(CaaS) both are apis' need to validate regard less data type or array. Need to write re-usable functions (I am already using bearer tokens, but need to implement with other).
3. same source and target validations but incorporate so many logics/expressions from source to target. can I adapt Karate framework for my testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate is very well suited for calling 2 APIs and comparing data. Karate has built-in support for [comparing arrays ignoring element order](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-contains-only). So here is one possible solution:

```
* def response1 = { empDetails: [ 100, 30, 50] }
* def response2 = { empDetails: [ 50, 100, 30] }
* match response1.empDetails contains only response2.empDetails
```

There are many more possibilities here since you can transform one payload and then do a compare. For further reading, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120851/143475

For example if you want to compare integers vs float-strings:

```
* def response1 = { empDetails: [ '100.0', '30.0', '50.0'] }
* def response2 = { empDetails: [ 50, 100, 30] }
* def expectedEmpDetails = response1.empDetails.map(x => parseInt(x))
* match response2.empDetails contains only expectedEmpDetails
```

Refer the docs on [type-conversions](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion) and [JSON transforms](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms).