# How to compare two jsonArrays in karate where they have different number of keys and different names

Tags: arrays, karate, feature-file

I have two jsonArrays which have keys with different name and I want to compare each json object in a separate feature file.

Is there any way I can pass two jsonArrays in a feature file and compare them.

**sample-create.feature**

```
* table kittens1 
  | name   | age | dept|
  | 'Bob'  |   2 | IT. |
  | 'Wild' |   1 | HR. |
  | 'Nyan' |   3 |ADMIN|

* table kittens2 
  | first_name    | emp_age   |
  | 'Bob'         |   "2"     |
  | 'Wild'        |   "1"     |
  | 'Nyan'        |   "3"     |


* def result = call read('cat-create.feature') kittens1 kittens2
```

**cat-create.feature**

```
@ignore
Feature:

Scenario:
  assert first_name == name
  assert parseInt(emp_age) == age
```

I am not able to pass jsonObject from both jsonArrays in another (cat-create.feature) feature file.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are making is `call` only takes one argument. Also note that any variables before the `call` are "visible" in the called feature. So you may already have what you want.

That said, I think you are over-complicating things and perhaps not yet appreciated the power of Karate and JSON arrays. I think the below will achieve what you want, without an extra `Feature:` or `call`.

```
* def data2 = kittens2.map(x => ({ name: x.first_name, age: parseInt(x.emp_age) }))
* match kittens1 contains deep data2
```

Please spend time reading these answers for more explanation of the above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120851/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475